# How to estimate ARIMA parameters for the set of time series

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation

If I have a set of time series. For example orders of the users.  How.can I estimate best p and q for the whole dataset not just one user history

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises normally when you have data for a number of groups/panels and you wish to subsequently test the hypothesis of a common set of parameters across all groups/panels. AUTOBOX has an option to do this [image] and I will detail here how the subsequent F test is setup.

For each panel of the k groups (each with possibly different sub-counts) estimate the error sos and then sum them over the groups. Noe concatenate the data from group 1 through group k and estimate the parameters using all of the data WITH the following constraint . The first p errors for each group must be constrained to be zero due to the autoregressive structure. Sum the error sos across all groups to obtain sosa.

I am unaware of any other off-the-shelf solution so you may have to program this yourself.

After obtaining the error sos for the composite (sosb) , construct a standard F test to test the difference between the two error sos ( i.e. sosa and sosb) taking into account the degrees of freedom.